# Regex for custom parsing

Tags: regex

Regex isn't my strongest point. Let's say I need a custom parser for strings which strips the string of any letters and multiple decimal points and alphabets.

For example, input string is "--1-2.3-gf5.47", the parser would return
"-12.3547". 
I could only come up with variations of this :

```
string.replaceAll("[^(\\-?)(\\.?)(\\d+)]", "")
```

which removes the alphabets but retains everything else. Any pointers?

More examples:
Input: -34.le.78-90
Output: -34.7890

Input: df56hfp.78
Output: 56.78

Some rules:

- Consider only the first negative sign before the first number, everything        else can be ignored.
- I'm trying to do this using Java.
- Assume the -ve sign, if there is one, will always occur before the
  decimal point.

Comment: How do we know which decimal point to remove and which '-' to remove? I don't think it would be possible unless there is a fixed rule for this. For example "remove all '-' after the first occurrence" and "remove all '.' after the first occurrence" might be manageable...

Comment: Which flavor of regex?

Comment: Yes, that's an acceptable rule. Will include that in the question.Thanks!

Comment: Can we remove any hyphen except one that occurs at the beginning of the string?

Comment: You will be better off reconstructing the output string in your programming language. Loop through the input string one character at a time, take only the first `-` and `.` and ignore all non-numeric characters.

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/ i test my regexes there

Comment: Need more info.  You mean consider only the first neg sign before the first number?  Are all strings this exact format?  If not, what could other formats be? Could all numeric positions have multiple digits?  If the string started with only one neg sign is that a positive number?

Comment: Added more information @Gary_W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this on ideone and it seemed to work. The comments should explain the code well enough. You can copy/paste this into Ideone.com and test it if you'd like.

It might be possible to write a single regex pattern for it, but you're probably better off implementing something simpler/more readable like below.

The three examples you gave prints out:

```
--1-2.3-gf5.47   ->   -12.3547
-34.le.78-90     ->   -34.7890
df56hfp.78       ->    56.78
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(strip_and_parse("--1-2.3-gf5.47"));
        System.out.println(strip_and_parse("-34.le.78-90"));
        System.out.println(strip_and_parse("df56hfp.78"));
    }

    public static String strip_and_parse(String input)
    {
        //remove anything not a period or digit (including hyphens) for output string
        String output = input.replaceAll("[^\\.\\d]", "");

        //add a hyphen to the beginning of 'out' if the original string started with one
        if (input.startsWith("-"))
        {
            output = "-" + output;
        }

        //if the string contains a decimal point, remove all but the first one by splitting
        //the output string into two strings and removing all the decimal points from the
        //second half           
        if (output.indexOf(".") != -1)
        {
            output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf(".") + 1) 
                   + output.substring(output.indexOf(".") + 1, output.length()).replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! I guess I was looking for some pure regex magic, but that seems unreasonable.

Comment: @Tara You can upvote the question, too, if you'd like. You now have enough rep to do it. :) Also, yes, I'm not even sure if pure regular expressions can remove characters like you want, since there doesn't seem to be a definitive pattern that a regular language could capture. But I could be wrong. Anyway, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of regex, the secondary, tertiary, etc., decimals seem tough to remove. However, this one should remove the additional dashes and alphas: `(?<=.)-|[a-zA-Z]`. (Hopefully the syntax is the same in Java; this is a Python regex but my understanding is that the language is relatively uniform).

That being said, it seems like you could just run a pretty short "finite state machine"-type piece of code to scan the string and rebuild the reduced string yourself like this:

```
a =  "--1-2.3-gf5.47"
new_a = ""
dash  = False
dot   = False
nums  = '0123456789'
for char in a:
    if char in nums:
        new_a = new_a + char  # record a match to nums
        dash  = True  # since we saw a number first, turn on the dash flag, we won't use any dashes from now on
    elif char == '-' and not dash:
        new_a = new_a + char  # if we see a dash and haven't seen anything else yet, we append it
        dash  = True  # activate the flag
    elif char == '.' and not dot:
        new_a = new_a + char  # take the first dot
        dot   = True  # put up the dot flag
```

(Again, sorry for the syntax, I think you need some curly backets around the statements vs. Python's indentation only style)

Comment: I get the essence of what you're trying there. But I was looking to solve this using regex, which I now realize is not straightforward. Thank you for the effort though :)